# Drupal - Unable to disable language prefix

Tags: drupal

**Background:**

I'm migrating a Drupal 7 site from server to another. At it's new location, there is a problem with the Drupal installation whereby none of the forms are being submitted correctly. After any form ha been submitted, the information has not been saved.

I think this has to do with the language prefix in the URL. Everything gets directed from say "http://newsite.dev/admin/modules" to "http://newsite.dev/en/admin/modules".  I think that this 'en' language prefix in the URL is causing the problem.

**Question:**

How can I disable the language prefix entirely?

I have tried disabling the 'locale' module directly in the database - but no joy.

Are there any Drupal boffins out there that can help?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the prefix in admin/config/regional/language/edit/en

I assume it is your default langage

hope it helps

PR

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. I've got the language prefix removed from the URL, thanks PR!